# How to resolve variables in JSON from another JSON?

Tags: java, json, properties, jackson

I have two json files, `versions.json` contains the variables and its respective values and `deploy.json` contains placeholders for these variables. Currently i am loading JSON through jackson and storing it in `Properties` and resolving using `PropertyPlaceholderHelper`.

`versions.json`

```
{
   "version1" : "0.1",
   "version2" : "0.2"
}
```

`deploy.json`

```
{
    "package1" : "$version1",
    "package2" : "$version2"
}
```

Java Code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("version1", versions.getVersion1());
props.put("version2", versions.getVersion2());

// Now resolving something like
PropertyPlaceholderHelper.resolvePlaceholder(deploy, props);
```

My problem is i need to update my code whenever a new package has been added. How can i resolve these variables without updating my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution through loading JSON file as properties.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 TypeReference<Properties> buildVersionsTypeReference = new TypeReference<Properties>() { };
 Object object = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);
 if (object instanceof Properties) {
        return (Properties) object;
  }
```

Earlier i have a custom class for `BuildVersion` and i am loading json into BuildVersion object and adding each member into properties.  Now i am loading directly into `Properties` and passing it to `PropertyPlaceholderHelper`.

```
PropertyPlaceholderHelper.resolvePlaceholder(deploy, properties);
```